# Table names don't conform to the IEEEtran format for table caption

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption, ieeetran, journal-publishing

My table captions don't conform to IEEE journal format. I wrote the below code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
   
\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison of test accuracies of classifiers on different features}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.42\textwidth}
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
Original Class & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class Predicted} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
1 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 27 & 0 & 0  \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0  \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 29  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\caption{Evaluation Metrics}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.9  & 1 & 0.97 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.98 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.02 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add something about what output you would like.

Comment: package `caption`, `sunbcaption` overwrite default `IEEEtran` settings. Remove them from preamble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, packages `caption` and `subcaption` overwrite default settings of `IEEEtran` document class. Instead of them yo should use `subfig` if you needed it:
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

An example how you can correct your MWE. It now contain your original presentation of your tables and new one with sub tables which has more sense:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb,mathtools}% nccmath had to be loaded before mathtools
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{caption,subcaption} % they are not compatible with ieeetran
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison of test accuracies of classifiers on different features}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.42\textwidth}
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
Original Class & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class Predicted} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
1 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 27 & 0 & 0  \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0  \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 29  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\caption{Evaluation Metrics}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.9  & 1 & 0.97 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.98 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.02 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison of test accuracies of classifiers on different features}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\subfloat[Confusion Matrix]
{
\begin{tabular*}{0.45\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
    \toprule
\makecell{Original\\ Class} 
  & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class Predicted} \\
    \cmidrule{2-9}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
    \midrule
1 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 27 & 0 & 0  \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 & 0  \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 29  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Evaluation Metrics]
{
\begin{tabular*}{0.45\linewidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.9  & 1 & 0.97 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.98 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.02 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0.03  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]