# How can I place multiple figures in multiple rows and columns in IEEEtran format?

Tags: tables, floats, ieeetran, subfig

I wrote a code to place multiple figures in multiple rows and columns:

```
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{caption,subcaption}
 %\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
 \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
 \usepackage{nccmath}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{placeins}
 \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
   
 \begin{document}
    
 \begin{figure*}[htb]
 \centering % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1}
 \caption{IEMG}
 \label{fig:1}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2}
 \caption{MAV}
 \label{fig:2}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3}
 \caption{MAV1}
 \label{fig:3}
 \end{subfigure}
   
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4}
 \caption{Variance}
 \label{fig:4}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{5}
 \caption{RMS}
 \label{fig:5}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{6}
 \caption{WL}
 \label{fig:6}
 \end{subfigure}
    
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{7}
 \caption{AAC}
 \label{fig:7}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \begin{subfigure}{0.30\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{8}
 \caption{DASDV}
 \label{fig:8}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
 \caption[Scatter plots for different features for data from first two sensors for 8 categories]
 {\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}Scatter plots for different features for data
  from first two \\sensors for 8 categories of  hand gestures\end{varwidth}}
 \label{fig:images}
 \end{figure*}
    
 \end{document}
```

It was working until I replaced `\usepackage{caption,subcaption}` with `\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}` to make my table captions conform to IEEEtran format.

Comment: Are you aware that `caption` and `subcaption` overwrite IEEEtran settings? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586308/table-names-dont-conform-to-the-ieeetran-format-for-table-caption/586311#586311, you may extend second example in answer to your number of `subfloat`s.

Comment: Yeah today I came to know that caption and subcaption overwrite IEEEtran settings but as a beginner I'm facing difficulties to modify my code to conform to IEEEtran settings.

Comment: It seems that your question is duplicate to your previous  question. Or  I do overlook 
 something?

Comment: Previous Q was about tables in IEEEtran format, this one related to figures.

Comment: There is no diference between tables and figures :-), I will try to write an answer ASAP.

Comment: Please do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially this your question is duplicate to your previous one. `\subfloat` is just a container in which is element of main float. In the case of table, in it is inserted table, if it is `figure`, in it is inserted figures.

Considering instruction for `IEEEtran` package *How to Use the IEEEtran LATEX Class* (written by package author and maintainer, section X), your MWE should be:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\linewidth}
\subfloat[IEMG]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 1
\hfill
\subfloat[MAV]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 2
\hfill
\subfloat[MAV1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 3

\subfloat[Variance]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 4
\hfill
\subfloat[RMS]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 5
\hfill
\subfloat[WL]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 6

\subfloat[AAC]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 7
\hfil
\subfloat[DASDV]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}% 8

\caption{Scatter plots for different features for data from first two  sensors for 8 categories of  hand gestures.}
\label{fig:images}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks. Just a little doubt - should fig main caption be in italics in IEEEtran format ?